# Python - Creating a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I wanted to create a list of dictionaries in python. The usual way of creating a list worked for me. That is `mylist = [{1:1},{2:2}]`

However, when I tried creating it using a comprehension over `range()` function, `mylist = [a:a for a in range(10)]` I get syntax error.

But to my surprise, if I construct a set in the same manner, it works as expected. `myset = {a:a for a in range(10)}`

May I know why this is so? I am using Python3

Comment: Looks like this is what we call a good question; it clearly needs more upvotes for missing research efforts and using wrong terms.

Comment: Your Python statement `myset = {a:a for a in range(10)}` doesn't construct a `set` but a `dict`. You have values in it, that you can access by indexing by the keys, e.g., `myset[5]` returns the value `5` while, by contrast, indexing a `set` data structure raises a `TypeError` because _"'set' object does not support indexing"_. If you want to have a _set comprehension in your code you have to write, more simply, `myset = {a for a in range(10)}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
mylist = [{a:a} for a in range(10)]
```

You forgot about `{` and `}`.

In the second example, your `myset` is a dict, not a set:

```
In [8]: type(myset)
Out[8]: dict
```

In this example, `{` and `}` denote [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), not set comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a dictionary creation in your list comprehension:

```
mylist = [{a:a} for a in range(10)]
```